# Communicate between two debian virtual machines in internal network ping

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, debian

I have two machines where I set the network as the Internal Network.

On the my debian1 on VBox I type:

`ifconfig eth0 192.168.254.253 up`

On the debian2 on VBox I type:

`ifconfig eth0 172.16.255.254 up`

I would like to virtual machines to be able to communicate with each other when I type `ping 192.168.254.243` on the debian2 I gets `network unreachable` and I don't known why...

EDIT:

I have one more problem. @MariusMatutiae Thanks for the reply.
I needs to configure network interfaces according to the following schedule:

[image]

Do it the same way as in response @MariusMatutiae using the ip addr and route?

Comment: Pls see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I do not know whether I should answer the OP or this question above,

> I want to do it for study. How to configure 3 machine? – lukassz yesterday

**OP**:

Do **not** use your commands to assign IP addresses to the two VMs. Instead, on first VM,

```
   ip addr add 192.168.115.1/24 dev eth0
```

on second VM,

```
   ip addr add 192.168.115.2/24 dev eth0
```

and now the two will be able to ping each other.

**Additional question**:

create a third VM (Linux) with **two** internal host adapters, belonging to **two** distinct nets, say one is called `intnet1` and the other `intnet2`.

On the third machine, give these commands:

```
      ip addr add 192.168.254.250/24 dev eth1
      ip addr add 172.16.255.250/24 dev eth2
      echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Now, make sure VM1 (192.168.254.253) is on `intnet1`, and VM2 is on `intnet2` (172.16.255.254). Also, on VM1:

```
      ip route add default via 192.168.254.250
```

and on VM2:

```
      ip route add default via 172.16.255.250
```

Now VM1 and VM2 will talk thru VM3.

Comment: I make your OP, After a while it started to work. To machine a saw without a router must be in the same class of IP addresses so?

Comment: @lukassz Yes, two machines without a router must be in the same subnet to be able to talk to each other.

Comment: Okay, I have one question. The command `ip addr` you use `192.168.254.250`. Then you talk about `192.168.254.253`. What is the relationship? Address `192.168.254.253` should be set using the `ifconfig`?

Comment: @lukassz the address 192.168.254.250 is on the **third** machine, the address 192.168.254.253 is the address**you** setup on the first machine. As for ifconfig, no,it is obsolete, better use `ip` always, on  all machines.

Comment: pls check my updated question

Comment: @lukassz You should ask a new question.

Comment: I tried to write new question http://superuser.com/questions/995014/communicate-between-two-debian-virtual-machines-in-internal-network-using-two-ro

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a wild guess here and suppose you don't know what subnetworking is. What you have done here is place two machines on two different subnetworks (one being 192.168.254.0/24 I suspect and the other being 172.16.0.0/16). If you want the two machines to talk to each other with those IP addresses then you need to have a route between the two networks. That is usually done with a router that takes one subnet and routes it to the next one.

Note that even though the cables and all seem to indicate that all your machines are in the same network then that is not true if your IP addresses are like the ones you describe with a subnet mask like I guess you have with my CIFS notation above. A network is described logically with IP addresses and subnet masks, not with wiring and cables.

Comment: My network conf: debian1: `ifconfig eth1 192.168.254.253 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` and debian2: `ifconfig eth1172.16.255.254 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` but ping still not working.

Comment: Should I set another machine to be a router?

Comment: What you need is to connect these two machines to a third machine that will function as a router or bridge between the two networks, or put them on the same network. Why do you want to have them on two separate networks?

Comment: I want to do it for study. How to configure 3 machine?

Comment: Are these two VirtualBox machines on the same host perhaps? If so then my guess was wrong. Then this has to do with NAT (network address translation) and you have to go read up a lot on that. I don't know how NAT works with VirtualBox so cant assist you there. See [this link](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) to understand NAT under VirtualBox and perhaps [this](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm) for a general introduction to NAT.