# Communicate between virtual machines in internal network using two routers

Tags: networking, router, debian

I would like to virtual machines to be able to communicate with each other. I needs to configure network interfaces according to the following schedule:
[image]

In this case, suffice it to any machine assign the IP address using the command ip addr?
And I will add ip route on BST routers?

All systems are running on virtual machines. Host is Windows.

BST1, BST2, Eagle-Server - Debian machines

PC1, PC2 - Windows machines

I'm using VirtualBox

Edit

My config:

```
Eagle:

       ip addr add  192.168.254.1/24 dev eth0
       ip route add 10.10.10.4/30 via 192.168.254.253 dev eth0
       ip route add 172.16.200.0/24 via 192.168.254.253 dev eth0
       ip route add 172.16.255.0/24 via 192.168.254.253 dev eth0
BST1

      ip addr add 192.168.254.253/24 dev eth0
      ip addr add 10.10.10.6/30 dev eth1
      ip route add 172.16.200.0/24 via 10.10.10.5 dev eth1
      ip route add 172.16.255.0/24 via 10.10.10.5 dev eth1
BST2

      ip addr add 10.10.10.5/30 dev eth1 
      ip addr add 172.16.255.254/24 dev eth0
      ip addr add 172.16.200.254/24 dev eth2
      ip route add 192.168.254.0/24 via 10.10.10.5 dev eth1
```

Ping between BST1 and Eagle does not work. Ping from PC1 (172.16.255.128) and PC2 (172.16.255.127) to BST2 - request timed out.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You've asked about two virtual machines, but your image shows 3 machines and 2 routers.  Which machines are you trying to configure?  Do you already have routers configured in the internal virtual environment?

Comment: Can yu please specify: which are VM's? Inside which host? Are BST1/BST2 Linux? Are you using VirtualBox?

Comment: Ok, I corrected the question. It is now understood?

Comment: @lukassz, what part of this are you having trouble with?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three internal nets:

1. intern0 between Eagle and BST1
2. intern1 between BTS1 and BTS2
3. intern2 between BTS2 and the two pcs;

Thus Eagle and the two pcs need only one network adapter, BTS1 need2 2, and you can configure BTS2 with 3 network adapters.

You need to enable IPv4 forwarding on BTS1 and BTS2 as follows:

```
     echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You may configure all the interfaces of Eagle, BTS1 and BTS2 with the ip command:

Eagle:

```
       ip addr add  192.168.254.1/24 dev eth0
       ip route add 10.10.10.4/30 via 192.168.254.253 dev eth0
       ip route add 172.16.200.0/24 via 192.168.25.253 dev eth0
       ip route add 172.16.255.0/24 via 192.168.25.253 dev eth0
```

BST1

```
      ip addr add 192.168.254.253/24 dev eth0
      ip addr add 10.10.10.6/30 dev eth1
      ip route add 172.16.200.0/24 via 10.10.10.5 dev eth1
      ip route add 172.16.255.0/24 via 10.10.10.5 dev eth1
```

BST2

```
      ip addr add 10.10.10.5/30 dev eth1 
      ip addr add 172.16.255.254/24 dev eth0
      ip addr add 172.16.200.254/24 dev eth2
      ip route add 192.168.254.0/24 via 10.10.10.5 dev eth1
```

You will need to configure the PCs in Windows (sorry no hablo Windows and want to keep it that way), to have the two static IPs you chose for them. Also, remember to use 172.16.200.254 as the default gateway for Kowalski, and 172.16.255.254 as the default gateway for Nowak.

That's all.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. I set up the connection so far between debian machines. I think you  made a mistake in the IP address, eg. `172.166.255.254` should be `172.15.255.254`. BST1 router can not send a ping to Eagle Server.

Comment: Something is wrong with the command `ip route` that ping does not work?

Comment: @lukassz You will have to tell me on which machine you are issuing the command, and to whom.

Comment: @lukassz Try , on BST1, `ping -b 192.168.254.253 -c1  IP_of_Eagle`

Comment: Still noting, ping from BST1 to Eagle Server does not work. IP of Eagle Server is: `192.168.254.254`. I tried send ping on BST1 machine to Eagle Server. Please check my IP table on image. BST1<>BST2 it's works.

Comment: I don't  understand this on Eagle `ip route add 172.16.200.0/24 via 192.168.25.253 dev eth0` both addresses point to other machines.

Comment: To ensure ping BST1 to Eagle. Prerequisite is `ip route` to Eagle?

Comment: @lukassz Yes, it is a prerequisite. I added routes for all pcs so that they can all talk to each other. Now, I have to work,will look at it tonight.

Comment: Ok, I try do this again.